# MySQL PHP insert new row where rowNum column values always remain chronological by date and time

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to create a SQL query (or multiple queries and logic in PHP) to insert new rows into MySQL db table (say table name is student) where the rowNum column values always remain chronological dependent on a separate date/time column. This means that if the row I'm inserting has the greatest/max/latest date/time it should be inserted normally and the rowNum value will just increment by one. I already have that implemented. The issue is that when the row I'm inserting has a date/time value that falls between two existing rows. Then the rowNum value for the row I'm inserting needs to be set to be the same as the rowNum value for the second of the two rows that I'm trying to insert "between" (Note: I understand the table is unordered list/set; however, the rowNum needs to adjust as in it is being insert "between"). Then, the rest of the rows after (chronologically speaking) this newly inserted row need to have their rowNum value incremented by one. Please see below example for further clarification:

id is autoincrement id column and primary key. rowNum is a "reference" id that is not necessarily unique, but does increment for each new insertion. If you go through each rowNum value, they should always be in chronological order based on date/time column. dateTime is not a default datetime timestamp, instead it is a varchar field in the format shown below.

Table: student

| id | rowNum | dateTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 09-17-2021 14:00 |
| 2 | 5 | 09-17-2021 16:32 |
| 3 | 6 | 09-18-2021 19:11 |
| 4 | 7 | 09-22-2021 13:01 |

Then, when insert a new row with dateTime: 09-17-2021 15:21 the table should be as follows:

Table: student

| id | rowNum | dateTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 09-17-2021 14:00 |
| 5 | 5 | 09-17-2021 15:21 |
| 2 | 5 | 09-17-2021 16:32 |
| 3 | 6 | 09-18-2021 19:11 |
| 4 | 7 | 09-22-2021 13:01 |

Then, the rowNum values after the inserted row should increment as follows:

Table: student

| id | rowNum | dateTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 09-17-2021 14:00 |
| 5 | 5 | 09-17-2021 15:21 |
| 2 | 6 | 09-17-2021 16:32 |
| 3 | 7 | 09-18-2021 19:11 |
| 4 | 8 | 09-22-2021 13:01 |

Lastly, I understand this is a strange thing to do. I've made this concern clear and suggested this should be done a different way; but, due to unique constraints I have to do it this way where the rowNum values are chronological.

Comment: "_rowNum is a "reference" id_" A reference to what? What is it used for? Does it have to be stored within the DB? What is your question?

Comment: Why not use [ROW_NUMBER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number)? (although it requires MySQL 8.0.)

Comment: @brombeer "rowNum" is just a reference to the record at that row. It has to be stored within the DB. It is essentially the record "name" that would be used in the real world to talk about the data at that row if that makes sense. For example a person, "Bill" could ask, what was the date and time that the record at rowNum 100 happened? My actual table has multiple other columns filled with other data. I just simplified the table in order to ask the question.

Comment: Also, your DATETIME data is in an invalid format. MySQL uses the YYYY-MM-DD format for dates. So your dates are actually strings, which means they might not be inserted as dates at all. What's to stop someone from inserting a row with `dateTime='banana'`?

Comment: @brombeer  As for my question, I am looking for suggestions on how such a SQL insert statement might be created or if there is an existing easy way to accomplish this. In my research I didn't find any other cases where someone had the same situation as me.

Comment: @BillKarwin In theory yes, they could try to enter a row with that dateTime; however, the dateTime is entered via a datepicker and validated in PHP. With that being said, I'd be open to storing as a MySQL DATETIME instead of varchar which I'm currently using if that would be considered "best practice"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INSERT cannot modify other rows than the row(s) it inserts. You also cannot use a trigger, because a trigger cannot update the same table (it could cause infinite loops).

So you must do an UPDATE statement after you finish your INSERT. Best if you do this in a transaction.

But actually it's easier to do the UPDATE first:

```
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE student SET rowNum=rowNum+1 WHERE rowNum >= 5;

INSERT INTO student SET rowNum=5, dateTime='09-17-2021 15:21';

COMMIT;
```

It's better to do the UPDATE first because if you INSERT the new row first, then it'll get included in the condition of the UPDATE.

This still has a problem, if more than one client is inserting a row concurrently. It could cause lock conflicts or deadlocks. You might need to use LOCK TABLES first to prevent this. But that will block your opportunity to do concurrent inserts. In other words, every transaction that does an INSERT will need to wait for others to commit.

You should also consider:

- What happens to the rowNum values if a row is deleted?
- What happens to the rowNum values if a dateTime is updated?
- What prevents a client from updating a rowNum value directly, and throwing off the unbroken sequence?

Comment: Concurrent insertions is already handled by only allowing one user to be logged in at once-I know, kind of an archaic solution, but it works and it is fine for my use case. I will look into your solution and mark as answer if it works for me. Appreciate the suggestion to consider row deletion/updates.

Comment: I don't want to think about the [WTFPM](http://reviewthecode.blogspot.com/2016/01/wtf-per-minute-actual-measurement-for.html) of your app.

Comment: Haha, well unfortunately that makes two of us...

Comment: So I was able to use this format where I used transactions, update statement, and insert statement. I was able to handle the deleting and updating situations similarly. In order to find where to increment rowNum starting at I did another query: SELECT * FROM student WHERE incident_date>='$userInputtedDatetime' ORDER BY rowNum ASC LIMIT 1. Then I saved the rowNum from this query in phpVariable to use in my transaction update query (...WHERE rowNum >= phpVariable).

Comment: Furthermore, I changed my DB so it is now using datetime datatype instead of varchar and am looking into locking tables to handle concurrency to see if this makes sense or if it would be a better solution for my application.